# L293D Motor driver 'braking' using input pins

Tags: impedance, l293d

I read the following on Wikipedia:

> Using pins 2 and 7 ( 15 and 10) to determine motor START/STOP or PWM duties it's dangerous, since there wouldn't be high impedance outputs: Current would flow back during the low semiperiod of PWM when the motor is turning.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motor_driver_L293d

I'm new to building electronic circuits and working on a small Arduino project. When I first connected my motor to the L293D motor driver my first thought on making the motor stop was setting both input pins low, which does indeed work. However, after reading the Wikipedia page; it seems like a bad idea.

What is the problem with not having a high impedance output and can someone explain what it basically means? Is it really that bad to brake using the input pins and should I use the enable pin instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That Wikipedia article is very poor. It doesn't even link to the datasheet or have a diagram of the pinout. Your question is similar to [Braking a motor with power transistors](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/227461/braking-a-motor-with-power-transistors/227536#227536).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNP3s2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Using the bridge to brake the motor.*

I would expect that you should be able to give maximum braking by holding closed one of the already closed switches and let the freewheel diodes look after the rest. This will initially maintain the current and rapidly cause dynamic braking. If the current is running left to right through the motor then SW1 could be left closed *or* SW4.

To simplify your control logic you can just close SW2 and SW4 each time you want to brake. The current through the switches and diodes just after braking is initiated will be the same current as immediately before braking and should decay as the motor decelerates.

Comment: So there is no problem in setting both low or high in order to stop the motor?

Comment: As far as I know, no.